# Fastest way to intersect lists in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models. Users, Pages, and Networks.

- Users have_many Networks
- Networks belong_to Users and Pages
- Pages have_many Networks.

I'm writing a `Page#visible_to?(user)` method, and was wondering if there was a faster/more efficient/better way than I'm currently doing. The method should return true if any of a User's Networks are also linked to the Page.

Current implementation:

```
def visible_to?(user)
  return true if networks.empty
  user_network_ids = user.networks.pluck(:id)
  !networks.detect { |network| user_network_ids.include?(network.id) }.nil?
end
```

Other options would include using the `&` operator to determine an intersection, or putting this method on User. Thoughts?

Comment: Is the data on SQL? Then use SQL to intersect instead of loading the whole thing into ruby first.

Comment: Where does the page come into play? Does `networks` contain the networks associated with a page?

Comment: The `visible_to?` method is on Page, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

You can simplify

```
!networks.detect { |network| user_network_ids.include?(network.id) }.nil?
```

into

```
newtworks.any? { |network| user_network_ids.include? network.id }
```

Although in this case it is much nicer (in my esoteric opinion) to just use set intersection for all of the heavy lifting:

```
def visible_to?(user)
  networks.empty? || (networks.map(&:id) & user.networks.pluck(:id)).any?
end
```

This will return true if there is an overlap or networks is empty.

Comment: Won't the detect be faster because it will break out when it finds the first one? Instead of doing the full intersect?

Comment: If you have N networks and U user-network-ids, your detect solution is O(NU) worst case and the intersection case is O(N+U) worst case.

Comment: Excellent. Good argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
def visible_to?(user)
  return true if networks.empty?
  (user.networks & networks).size > 0
end
```

Comment: Apparently it should yield `true` when `networks` is empty, in which case your answer should include a `networks.empty? or ...` at the start.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers: Yes, Modified my answer

Comment: Won't the detect be faster because it will break out when it finds the first one? Instead of doing the full intersect?

Answer (score 0):

Using just the database, you could do:

```
Page.joins(networks: :user).where(pages: {id: page_id}, users: {id: user_id}).any?
```

It generates this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pages"
  INNER JOIN "networks" ON "networks"."page_id" = "pages"."id"
  INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "networks"."user_id"
WHERE "pages"."id" = <<page_id>> AND "users"."id" = <<user_id>>
```

What is fastest really depends on your specific case and how your data is distributed. For example, if the user's networks and the page's networks were already both selected because you also need them elsewhere, and there aren't many elements to compare, then it might be faster to do `(user.networks & page.networks).any?`. Just experiment a bit and find out what works best for you.